# Can we have two or more website hosted on a computer with IIS

Tags: networking, iis-7, web, intranet

I have an Virtual machine which has R2 2008 with an website which just works fine. I was wondering if there's any way we could host multiple websites on that server. Since its virtual we can add couple nic's if we'd like so more IP's.

Any ideas how else we could achieve this ?

Thanks for replying and reading the question....

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but question is not really clear. Yes you can host any number of websites on that server there is no restriction.

If you know the difference between website and web application then:

Follow this to create website :

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772350(v=ws.10).aspx

Follow this to create web applications:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772042(v=ws.10).aspx